# Is Spring-GraphQL a good replacement to RSQL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, dynamicquery, rsql

[RSQL](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser) is a query language for parametrized filtering of entries in RESTful APIs, meaning I can do something like

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/api/v1/employee?search=lastName==Doe
```

where the search query param can take multiple filters -

```
search=lastName==Doe;firstName==John
```

which translates to `select * from employee where firstName = 'John' and lastName = 'Doe'`

In GraphQL I need to define a schema in `schema.graphqls` which only supports a fixed query as -

```
type Query {
   employeeByLastName(lastName: String): Employee
   employeeByFirstName(firstName: String): Employee
}
```

**Is it possible to define a single query in GraphQL that can filter on any field without specifying the field explicitly in the schema?**

Something like -

```
type Query {
   filter(params: String[]): Employee
}
```

Note: I am new to GraphQL, I am following this [link](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/)

Comment: The main purpose of graphql is that you're explicit about fields to grab

Comment: If Graphql is only used to grab certain fields, it is limited to only a few use-cases where the response is optimized due to a large number of fields. But if the superset (of fields) is not too big, why can't the upstream service just pick the fields it needs from the superset returned?

Comment: It could. GraphQL and REST are not exclusive